# Angular-Datatables not accepting any ajax DTOptions

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.3, angular-datatables

I have this piece of code. I have tried 3 types of ajax calling, but no one works. I am getting the same error:

```
var getTableData = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('api/carregargridamenidades').then(function(result) {
        defer.resolve(result.data);
    });
    return defer.promise;
};

//first option
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
.newOptions()
.fromFnPromise(function() {                              (1)
    return $resource('api/carregargridamenidades').query().$promise;
})
.withBootstrap()
.withOption('processing', true)
.withPaginationType('full_numbers');

//second option
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
.newOptions()
.fromSource(getTableData())                              (2)
.withBootstrap()
.withOption('processing', true)
.withPaginationType('full_numbers');

//Third option
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
.newOptions()
.withOption('ajax', {                                    (3)
    url: 'api/carregargridamenidades'
})
.withBootstrap()
.withOption('processing', true)
.withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

The respective errors:

```
(1) TypeError: DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions(...).fromFnPromise is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (amenidade-controller.js:47)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
    at S.instance (angular.min.js:89)
    at p (angular.min.js:65)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)

(2) TypeError: DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions(...).fromSource is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (amenidade-controller.js:43)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
    at S.instance (angular.min.js:89)
    at p (angular.min.js:65)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)

(3) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:48
    at i (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
    at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

I am using the angular-datatables version below:

/*!
 * angular-datatables - v0.5.5
 * https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables
 * License: MIT
 */

And I am getting data from actions in Laravel 5.3 controllers, like:

```
public function carregarGrid()
{
    //Recupera todos os objetos cadastrados
    $objs = Amenidade::all();

    return $objs;
}
```

My wish is to make "Loading ..." message appears inside datatable, while my ajax is getting data, but this simple step is making me crazy. I am using suggestions got from stackoverflow and from angular-datatables site (http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#/api).

Is there a simple solution for this simple question ?

Thanks.

Comment: Facing same issue, did you get any solution?